# Grid output in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I am trying to show the output of the mysql in PHP in a Grid type of way!

I am using this code:

```
<?php 
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 6");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $dynamicList .= '<div class="shadow" id="products_holder"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="160" height="150" border="0" /></a>£' . $price . '<br></br>' . $product_name . '</div>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

it works absolutely fine but it doesn't output the data in a Grid way!!

Everything goes under each other instead of lets say 5 at the top and 5 at the bottom in like lines!

There are some tutorials on internet about grid output but it uses Tables and I am using Div. so that is where I am confused and stuck.

Comment: This kind of thing is what tables are there for. Why do you want to use div's?

Comment: Because the Div I have has some styling applied to it that is impossible to apply those styles to a table.

Comment: It's never impossible to apply CSS styles to a table element.

Comment: @Pekka웃, and Div's are more SEO friendly these days. seems like search engines like them better than tables.

Comment: that's nonsense. `div`s do *nothing* to enhance a document's semantic or SEO value. If you have tabular data, the right thing is to use tables. What you are probably referring to is that it's no longer cool to use tables for *layout*, which is true. It has nothing to do with this situation, though.

Comment: Use tables. All your reasons for avoiding them are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this and modify it according to your needs:

```
$dynamicList .= '<div class="shadow tr" id="products_holder"><div class="td"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="160" height="150" border="0" /></a></div><div class="td" >£' . $price . '<br></br>' . $product_name . '</div></div>';
```

And use some css as:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .tr{float:left;width:200px;}
 .td{float:left;width:160px;height:150px;border:1px solid black;}
</style>
```

Last but not least, remove id="products_holder" from your code as it will produce multiple divs with same id which is a bad bad practice.

**UPDATE:**
For your new question i.e. you want to put 5 rows separately something like this should work:

```
 if($i==0 || $i % 5 == 0){ 
 $dynamicList .= '<div class="table">';
  } 
$dynamicList .= '<div class="shadow tr" id="products_holder"><div class="td"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="160" height="150" border="0" /></a></div><div class="td" >£' . $price . '<br></br>' . $product_name . '</div></div>';
 if($i==0 || $i % 5 == 0){ 
  $dynamicList .= '</div><div style="clear:both"></div>';// div-table ends here
 }
```

Modify your css and add a class as:

```
<style>
.table{float:left;width:160px;}
</style>
```

Comment: And.. if everyone is suggesting to use tables.. just close your eyes and go for it.. there is a reason they are called tables: they show data in tabular format.

Comment: Nothing @Pekka웃 :) As the requirement is so rigid so I kind of suggested some workaround. I too have suggested in the comment to use tables.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much. but 1 question! How do I limit each row to just lets say 5 and then start another line of 5?

Comment: @user2056633 I have modified the answer, have a look and update your code with the hints.

Comment: Man you are my hero. how can I thank you mate? I haven't even tested it yet but just your effort and simple answers are awesome. you are awesome. :)

Comment: @gaurav, that worked as well. so Thank you so much. but the products are sitting on the top of each other. what I mean is that the div's/tables containing the products data (pictutes, name and price) are collapsing on the top of eachother! is there a <br> command needed somewhere in the code?

Comment: @user2056633: I have modified the answer, please check it, basically '<br />' can't do much with the floating divs so have added '<div style="clear:both"></div>'. Not sure but think it should work. And.. to accept an answer you can follow this: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as accepting answers will increase your accept ratio which will ultimately result in more people taking your questions seriously :)

Comment: @gaurav, Thank you for you help. that last update didn't work. it basically make the products show in a vertical line! what I need to do is to show them in two horizontal lines of 5 products in each line!  any suggestions? also, I keep refersh my page to see if I can see/find this accept button and I can't see it anywhere on this page!!!! very strange!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use divs instead of tables:

- do not use the same id for all items, you'll encounter problems later on. Instead, use multiple classes.
- add some CSS that will make each `div` a limited size box, such as

  .shadow { width: 20%; float: left; padding: 10px; }

  to achieve the grid effect. You will probably encounter problems if the items do not have the same height, so you'll have to either ensure it (  same size images etc ) or use some javascript to make them the same height.

Comment: yes, the images will be resized before uploaded using PHP. still haven't got my answer tho!! :)

Comment: as I said, apply the above CSS to the div -- that will give you 5 "tiles" per row